# python 2.7 force round up 2 decimal places

Tags: python, floating-point, decimal, rounding

I'm trying to force a float to round up to the 2nd decimal place. I know this isn't the best practice, but it's what I need for a program I'm working on. So for example:

100.00 = 100.00

100.001 = 100.01

100.009 = 100.01

I've gotten pretty close to the results i need with math.ceil and a tip i read in another post, but am running into an issue where if the input number already ends exactly in 2 decimal places, it's rounding up unnecessarily. Here is an example:

```
import math

taxpcnt = 1.12
roomsubtotal = 699.00

roomttl = math.ceil(taxpcnt * roomsubtotal * 100) / 100

print roomttl
```

This I would think would return 782.88, since 699 * 1.12 is exactly 782.88, but instead it returns 782.89. Weirder is if i 'print taxpcnt * roomsubtotal', i get 782.88. If i change the code to:

```
roomttl = math.ceil(782.88 * 100) / 100
```

I get the correct value. But some reason, all together it's not calculating right.

Any tips on how to properly get what I'm trying to achieve?

Edit: I think I have patched together a solution:

```
import math

taxpcnt = 1.12
roomsubtotal = 699.00

rate = "%.2f" % (taxpcnt * roomsubtotal * 100)
rate = float(rate)

roomttl = math.ceil(rate) / 100
```

Not sure if this is the best method, but at least it seems to work.

Comment: if you're dealing with money, try doing all your calculations in cents (or pence, or whatever currency you're dealing with). So, instead of 782.88, use 78288, and convert at the very end with string formatting. Alternatively, use Decimal.decimal().

Comment: Also, instead of multiplying and dividing by 100, you can use round(), of which second argument is the digits to round. That mixed with Decimal should bring you an easy solution.

Comment: @MattDMo: Performing arithmetic in units of cents does not fix arithmetic problems. If the arithmetic uses floating-point, it still has floating-point errors. if the arithmetic uses integers, it still has integer errors. E.g., in this question, a monetary amount is multiplied by 1.12. Even if the monetary amount were in cents, the product would include some multiple of .12 cents. That would be lost in integer arithmetic, which truncates. Then, since the fractional amount has been lost, it is not present to be rounded up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the world of floating point. Have a read of [this](http://floating-point-gui.de/) to get an idea of what's going on.

The result of `699 * 1.12` cannot be accurately represented by the computer, so the rounded result is incorrect.

```
>>> 699 * 1.12
782.8800000000001
```

If you only care about two decimal places consider using a different type, such as a [`Decimal`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html).

Comment: Thank you. I've used some of this information to kind of put together a solution (posted as an edit to my post)